# Binding to OPOS MSR DataEvent with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, activex, opos

I have implemented an MSR OPOS ActiveX control for use in an IE-based web application.  I have tested the device and it works; however, I'm trying to port the VBScript code found [here](http://www2.clearlake.ibm.com/store/support/tools/msrexample.html) to JavaScript for easier maintainability.

I'm having trouble binding to the `DataEvent` with JavaScript though -- when I put the card to the reader, the data definitely appears to take, as I can query the object directly through the console with `ReaderControl.Track1Data` and see that there is in fact data there.

In the VBScript version, there seems to be a method called `[control]_DataEvent` that you can simply override in order to bind to the event.  I have tried `ReaderControl.attachEvent("DataEvent", function() { alert(ReaderControl.Track1Data); })`, which *does* seem to work, for some reason, **only** when subsequently set `ReaderControl.DataEventEnabled = true;`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think so, it was a while ago, so I'm going from memory here -- but I think the issue was that after a read, I had to subsequently release the device, or something along those lines, then re-prepare it for a read.  I'll have to try to dig and find the code but I've since changed jobs.